# Facebook canvas application most elegant way

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I'm currently working on a Facebook canvas application. what I need is accessing user data like name, id, likes, events and friends.

As far as I know there are lot of ways to do this, facebook api, graph api, etc.

my platform is PHP, and i've already created an application on the developers site.

can you write me a short example of how to request permissions from the Facebook user, and how to access his or her data and friends list for example? All the other tutorials are about integration your site with facebook, or using old methods.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Too broad of a question.  Please pare it down to a more manageable size.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is just the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), there's no other "facebook api". Though, you can also use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) if you want/need.

Here's the tutorial about canvas applications: [Apps on Facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/).
There's a sdk for [javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and one for [php](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) that you can use.

As for the permissions and such: [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Please read those tutorials/documentation and come back with a more specific question.